# Monitor MySQL table changes in real time with PHP/AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Yet another post in the chatroom saga.
I am working on a PHP chat application similar to Discord, and it uses a database to store messages. The problem is that currently I only have it on a refresh loop which is using too much RAM when someone is connected to the site. I am trying to build a sort of mysql watcher that would refresh the page, but only when the table is updated. The thing is I have no idea where to start, I think I might be able to do this with AJAX but I am a total Java noob. So far, I have this:

```
$host = 'localhost:3306';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'root';
$database = 'sys';
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

$query = "select sent_time from messageTable order by id desc limit 1";

$current = $conn->query($query);

while (TRUE) {
    $newQuery = "select sent_time from messageTable order by id desc limit 1";
    $newCurrent = $conn->query(newQuery);
    if ($newCurrent != $current) {
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

For some reason, this is not working. How might i be able to fix this?
All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look up Sockets in PHP and JS

Comment: Websockets or Server Sent Events are a better fit for this kind of use case.